# How to move all files with names starting with a string from a list?

Tags: files, move

I have a file `strings.txt` with a list of strings:

```
GCA_001677475.1
GCA_003410275.1
GCA_002310615.1
GCA_000007405.1
GCA_000219515.3
```

And I have many files in a directory with names like:

```
GCA_000005845.2_ASM584v2_protein.faa
GCA_000006925.2_ASM692v2_protein.faa
GCA_000007405.1_ASM740v1_protein.faa
GCA_000007445.1_ASM744v1_protein.faa
GCA_000008865.2_ASM886v2_protein.faa
GCA_000009565.2_ASM956v1_protein.faa
```

I need to move only those files whose names start with a pattern from `strings.txt`. So far I've tried using `xargs` with `mv`:

```
cat strings.txt | xargs -I % mv %*faa ./Data
```

But `mv` doesn't see `%*faa` as a regex and tries to find files with this exact name (and of course it can't find any). I've also tried using `ls` but it works the same way:

```
cat strings.txt | xargs -I {} ls {}*faa
```

So how can I do that?

Comment: Unix&Linux StackExchange isn't a place where you can get people doing your (home)work for free. It's a place where you submit what you already tried, the error you met, and  *then* people will help you making it work. So please, provide that you tried and we will try helping you.

Comment: well, I've tried different things. 
for example, neither this
```cat strings.txt | xargs -I {} ls {}*faa``` nor this one
```cat strings.txt | xargs -I % mv %*faa ./Data``` didn't work.

Comment: @Somestudent Please [edit] your question and add your attempted solution there instead of writing a comment. Explain how it doesn't work. Show the error message or wrong output or describe the wrong result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
cat strings.txt | xargs -I '%' find . -type f -name "%*" -exec mv -t your_path {} +
```

Moved `GCA_000007405.1_ASM740v1_protein.faa` that is the only match.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
xargs bash -O nullglob -c '
    for prefix do
        set -- "$prefix"*.faa
        [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && mv -- "$@" ./Data
    done' sh <strings.txt
```

This uses `xargs` to give the strings in `strings.txt` to an in-line `bash` script in batches.

For each string, the in-line `bash` script tests whether there is any filenames matching the string in the current directory (adding `*.faa` to the end to create a pattern), and if so, these are moved to the `Data` directory, which is assumed to already exist.

The `nullglob` shell option is set for the in-line script to make sure that if the constructed pattern does *not* match anything, the pattern is removed (rather than retained unexpanded).

I'm testing explicitly whether the pattern matches because there are strings in your example that does not match any of the filenames that you show.  This is done by setting the list of positional parameters to  the result of the glob expansion and then testing whether the list's length (`$#`) is greater than zero.

You could obviously also have done this without `xargs` like so:

```bash
shopt -s nullglob

while IFS= read -r prefix; do
    set -- "$prefix"*.faa
    [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && mv -- "$@" ./Data
done <strings.txt
```

This would still *fail* if one of your prefix strings happened to match many thousands of filenames (the `mv` command line would become too long).  If that is the case, you would possibly use

```bash
shopt -s nullglob

while IFS= read -r prefix; do
    set -- "$prefix"*.faa
    if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$@" | xargs sh -c 'mv -- "$@" ./Data' sh
    fi
done <strings.txt
```

This is assuming that neither prefix strings nor filenames contain embedded newlines.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `xargs` or anything complicated. If all of the files are in the same directory, it should be enough to do:

```
$ while read string; do 
    mv "$string"_* ./Data; 
  done < strings.txt
```

Or, if your names can start with a `-` or you might have other weird characters in them, use:

```
$ while read -r string; do 
    mv -- "$string"_* ./Data; 
  done < strings.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty hack: `cat strings.txt| xargs -i sh -c 'mv {}* your/path/'>&/dev/null`

Less more correct hack: `export dir=$(ls -1); cat strings.txt| xargs -i sh -c 'grep "^{}" <<<$dir && mv {}* your/path'; dir=""`